# How to fix Shared Preferences is returning null string in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, sharedpreferences

I am using **shared preferences** to store and load values of a **Map in Flutter**, but am getting an error

```
The following assertion was thrown building UserPro(dirty):
A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart':
Failed assertion: line 360 pos 10: 'data != null'
```

Surely I understand that *Shared Preferences is returning a null String value*, but I don't understand why, since I am waiting for the value. And how to fix it. I am attaching my code with this question for your reference

----Storing ------

```
void setUserValues() async{
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    currentUser.forEach((k,v)=>sharedPrefs.setString(k, v));
  }
```

Here **currentUser** contains the map that contains user data like "Name", "Email", etc.

----Loading ------

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

SharedPreferences localStorage;


class UserPro extends StatelessWidget{
  final currentUser;

  String name;
  UserPro({this.currentUser}){
    name=localStorage.getString("Name");;
  }
  static Future init() async{
    localStorage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text(
            name,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 15,
              fontFamily: 'Berlin Sans FB',
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to wait for Shared preference to be initialized. Where are you calling the init() method?

Answer (score 0):

Use FutureBuilder

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

//SharedPreferences localStorage;


class UserPro extends StatelessWidget{
  final currentUser;

  //String name;
  UserPro({this.currentUser});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: FutureBuilder<SharedPreferences>(
             future: SharedPreferences.getInstance(),
             builder: (context,snapshot){
                if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                   return CircularProgressIndicator();
                  }
            return Text(
            snapshot.data.getString("name"),
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 15,
              fontFamily: 'Berlin Sans FB',
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
      },
   ),
    ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I need one more help, I am getting this error [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getAll on channel plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences)

I ran the flutter cleaner, pub get and wiped out emulator data and ran it again, but am getting the same error again

Comment: For me , uninstalling the app on emulator and re building project solves that issue. Often happens when the plugin is used for the first time

Comment: I did wipe the emulator data again, cleaned the build tree and cold booted the emulator and am still getting the same error, tried downgrading shared preferences from 0.5.10 to 0.5.9 but still am getting the same error

Comment: Raising an issue on SharedPreferences github repo would be more helpful